# Getting "failed to start accepting connection" while deploying my app into bluemix

Tags: node.js, db2, ibm-cloud

Hi Am facing "failed to start accepting connection" error while pushing or deploying my app to bluemix. Can any help me in that.... my code snippet as given below:

```
var express     = require('express');
app         = express();
var ibmbluemix  = require('ibmbluemix') 
var ibmdb = require('ibm_db');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var logger = ibmbluemix.getLogger();
var PORT = (process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 8000);
var HOST = (process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || 'localhost');
var queryData = null;
var serviceName = 'SQLDB';

if (process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) {
   var env = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES);
   db2 = env['sqldb'][0].credentials;
}
else{
   console.error("INFORMATION FOR DB CONNECTION NOT FOUND");
}

var dbConnection = "DRIVER={DB2};DATABASE=" + db2.db + ";UID=" +  db2.username + ";PWD=" + db2.password + ";HOSTNAME=" + db2.hostname +  ";port=" + db2.port;
console.log("Connection String: " + dbConnection);

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log('Creating the http server');
    ibmdb.open(dbConnection, function(err, conn) {
        if (err) {
            response.send("error occurred " + err.message);
        }
        else {
            console.log('before select');
            conn.query("SELECT FULL_NAME,  PASSWORD,  SHORT_ID FROM USER02130.USER_DETAILS", function(err,  rows, moreResultSets) {
                console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                console.log('no of records is '+rows.length);
                response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                response.write(JSON.stringify(rows));
                response.end();
            });
        }

}).listen(PORT, HOST);
```

Can anyone help me in this, Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to run it locally?

Comment: No, my SQLDB is in bluemix....so am directly deploying into buemix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few syntactical errors in your snippet (missing closing brackets etc). Try using this instead:

```
var express     = require('express');
app = express();
var ibmbluemix  = require('ibmbluemix') 
var ibmdb = require('ibm_db');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var logger = ibmbluemix.getLogger();
var PORT = (process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 8000);
var HOST = (process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || 'localhost');
var queryData = null;
var serviceName = 'SQLDB';

if (process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) {
   var env = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES);
   var db2 = env['sqldb'][0].credentials; // missed declaration
}
else{
    console.error("INFORMATION FOR DB CONNECTION NOT FOUND");
}

var dbConnection = "DRIVER={DB2};DATABASE=" + db2.db + ";UID=" +  db2.username + ";PWD=" + db2.password + ";HOSTNAME=" + db2.hostname +  ";port=" + db2.port;
console.log("Connection String: " + dbConnection);

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log('server request'); // does not create a server on every request
    ibmdb.open(dbConnection, function(err, conn) {
        if (err) {
            response.send("error occurred " + err.message);
        }
        else {
            console.log('before select');
            conn.query("SELECT FULL_NAME,  PASSWORD,  SHORT_ID FROM USER02130.USER_DETAILS", function(err,  rows, moreResultSets) {
                console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                console.log('no of records is '+rows.length);
                response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                response.write(JSON.stringify(rows));
                response.end();
            });
        }
    }) // missed closing brackets
}).listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log("Server running at "+HOST+" on port "+ PORT);
```

Node.js is very easy to set up locally, get it [here](https://nodejs.org/download/). Running it locally can help you identify many problems, such as syntactical error.

Hope it helps!

Comment: i need to use  http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
}
because once the client send request though url then need to send data as response to client

Comment: i have one doubt,  If i want to do user validation after selecting data by using userId...
How can i achieve that....?

Answer (score 0):

```
cf logs <app name> --recent
```

This command will give you the logs which will show you where your syntax errors were.

Answer (score -1):

It's great that you figured it out, but for future reference, the “failed to start accepting connection” error usually means the code threw an exception during initialization *before* calling `http.createServer(...).listen(port, host)`. Try adding the code below prior to the call to `listen(...)`

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Your console logs will then include a helpful stack trace if the startup code fails for an unforeseen reason instead of receiving the default "app crashed" message.

Still stuck? Pat Mueller offers other helpful suggestions in [Node.js debugging starts with better logging!](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/03/10/node-js-better-logging/) and David Clements' [Node.js tips #1: develop debugging techniques](http://www.nearform.com/nodecrunch/node-js-develop-debugging-techniques/) offers more advanced debugging tips, e.g., function de-anonymizing.